# Sorting C# List based on its element

Tags: c#, sorting, element

I have the C# class as follows :

```
public class ClassInfo {
    public string ClassName;
    public int BlocksCovered;
    public int BlocksNotCovered;


    public ClassInfo() {}

    public ClassInfo(string ClassName, int BlocksCovered, int BlocksNotCovered) 
    {
        this.ClassName = ClassName;
        this.BlocksCovered = BlocksCovered;
        this.BlocksNotCovered = BlocksNotCovered;
    }
}
```

And I have C# List of ClassInfo() as follows

```
List<ClassInfo> ClassInfoList;
```

How can I sort ClassInfoList based on BlocksCovered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This returns a `List<ClassInfo>` ordered by `BlocksCovered`:

```
var results = ClassInfoList.OrderBy( x=>x.BlocksCovered).ToList();
```

Note that you should really make `BlocksCovered` a property, right now you have public fields.

Answer (score 7):

```
myList.Sort((x,y) => x.BlocksCovered.CompareTo(y.BlocksCovered)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the `List<T>` object, use the `Sort()` method provided by `List<T>` as follows.

```
ClassInfoList.Sort((x, y) => x.BlocksCovered.CompareTo(y.BlocksCovered));
```

If you use the `OrderBy()` Linq extension method, your list will be treated as an enumerator, meaning it will be redundantly converted to a `List<T>`, sorted and then returned as enumerator which needs to be converted to a `List<T>` again.

Comment: FWIW, LINQ is usually smart enough to take advantage of underlying types, e.g. Count() will use ICollection<T>'s count property.  I don't know about Sort() though.

Comment: +1 I agree in general, but on lists of "normal" size this is not an issue so I personally shoot for *readability*, and that's where the LINQ syntax is clearly better. Also the overall Big O doesn't change - sorting is O(n*log n), traversal is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Linq, for example:

```
ClassInfoList.OrderBy(c => c.ClassName);
```

Comment: the OrderBy doesn't affect the orginal list, it creates another list

Comment: True, but why is that relevant? If you want to sort the list permanently, then save the results as a new list.